# Link to release runtime in debug mode

Tags: c++, debug-mode

I have code which only works in debug mode thanks to some faulty third party library.

Since I use quite a bit of std::vector, the code is rather slow in debug mode (since it uses the debug STL), and now someone said to use the runtime libraries instead.

I swapped the Code Generation from /MDd to /MD, and now my code fails on some basic functions.

For example I have code which pulls data from a file like this:

```
    template <class T> void ExtractData(std::string fileName, int& dataSize, std::vector<T>& data) {
    std::ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(fileName, std::ios_base::binary);

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        myfile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        int size = (int)(myfile.tellg());
        dataSize = size / sizeof(T);
        data.resize(size / sizeof(T));
        myfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        myfile.read( (char*)&data.at(0), size );
    }

    myfile.close();
}
```

and this code fails on myfile.seekg() with some exception in ntdll.dll

What can I do about this?

Comment: Compile the third-party library in a separate module, in debug mode. Compile the *rest* of the application in release mode.

Comment: I agree with Cody, isolate the faulty spots

Comment: Mixing the debug mode standard library and the release mode standard library is a one-way ticket to undefined behavior land via ODR violations if you are not very careful.